# C# Decoding YouTube videos at frame level

Tags: c#, opencv, youtube, mp4, decoder

I have an app that works with downloaded YouTube videos.  This application needs frame-level (Bitmap format) access to the video. The basic operations needed "Seek to frame X" and "Read frame".

OpenCV works really well at providing Bitmap frames from videos and is what my application uses.  They have "Seek to Frame" and "Read Frame" calls, callable from C#.

I'm searching for APIs that can provide this kind of access to YouTube videos that are on still on YouTube.

Is it possible to work with YouTube videos at the frame level without first downloading the entire video?

Comment: From the legal point of view, it is hardly possible at all: https://www.youtube.com/static?gl=US&template=terms 4C: You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer!

I suspected a potential problem, but wasn't sure.  Perhaps other (paid) hosting services can be more accommodating.